# GoogleSignInResult result. isSuccess() always returns false

Tags: java, android, google-signin

I have done my research on this problem... on all of the other posts on this topic and I am still stuck.

The version of my app is registered as a debug version.... so no need to create a **signed APK**?

I have made sure that I used the **Client-ID** from the **web-app** and not from android version of project.

I used an **SHA-1** when setting up my app on google console.

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestServerAuthCode("/*client_id goes in here*/")
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this
                   /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
```

That section of code went in my **onCreate** method.

The following went in my **onActivityResult Handler**.

**GOOGLE_SIGN_IN** constant was predefined.

```
        if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Google Login Details:" + result.getStatus().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
```

The final part is my **google sign in result handler**.

```
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Welcome "+acct.getDisplayName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent MainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(MainActivity);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

All the rest of the code used to get google login API to work is the same as those in the docs.

The **result.getStatus()** method in the activity handler doesnt display the usual 12050 error, that would indicate a configuration problem. Instead it says statusCode=DEVELOPER, resolution=null

Any Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Also, no errors or indications as to what the problem is in my logcat....

Answer (score 0):

I solved it..

The app that I created was using an old SSH-1 from an old laptop...

I needed to change the SSH-1 to the one on my laptop.